# Pull SwipeRefreshLayout to refresh RecyclerView In Fragment in android but Not Working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, pull-to-refresh

How can I refresh RecyclerView through SwipeRefreshLayout? I have searched a lot on google but its not working. Here is my code in fragment 
I am fetching data from server through Jason Parsing and getting into array and setting array into my RecyclerView adapter. Data is showing fine but SwipeRefreshLayout not working.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
   public  RecyclerView recyclerView;
   public  SwipeRefreshLayout mswipeRefreshLayout;
  public static MyRecyclerAdapter searchAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "FirstFragment";
    MyRecyclerAdapter myRecyclerAdapter;
    ArrayList<DataStored>dataStoredArrayList;
    private ParseDataClass mparser;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment,null);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.mFirstRecyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        mswipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipelayoutm);
        mparser = new ParseDataClass(getActivity());
        mparser.setOnDataRetrievalCallback(new OnDataRetrievalCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDataRetrieval(ArrayList<DataStored> dataSet) {
                dataStoredArrayList=dataSet;
                myRecyclerAdapter=new MyRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),dataStoredArrayList,mswipeRefreshLayout);
                searchAdapter =myRecyclerAdapter;
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);
            }
        });
        mparser.execute("http://192.168.3.10/fetchtext.php", "1");
         recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                if (scrollX == 0) {
                    mswipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                } else mswipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });
        mswipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                Refreshlist();
                mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void Refreshlist() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dataStoredArrayList.clear();
                myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mparser = new ParseDataClass(getActivity());
                mparser.setOnDataRetrievalCallback(new OnDataRetrievalCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataRetrieval(ArrayList<DataStored> dataSet) {
                        dataStoredArrayList.addAll(dataSet);
                        myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                mparser.execute("http://192.168.3.10/fetchtext.php", "1");

            }
        }, 0);
    }


}
```

Comment: set mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); immediately after myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have already done that but not working  I think this approach which I am following is wrong.

Comment: Please see all the code of fragment

Comment: RefreshList function isn't working here is problem in RefreshList  function

Comment: You are intentionally adding a delay? of 3 seconds? and why ur adding callback again? mparser.setOnDataRetrievalCallback in Refreshlist.

Comment: I found many bugs in your fragment class, can you post your complete fragment class so that i edit it for you.

Comment: I have uploaded all My fragment code here that's all

Comment: how can I get Refresh/again ArrayList without calling again mparser.setOnDataRetrievalCallback in Refreshlist and how can I set  refresh list to RecyclerView  without creating adapter again?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` immediately after fetching syntax, whereas it should be in block of callback when response comes.
Also i found some issues in your fragment class that will create view inconsistency.

Like you are setting adatper two times, you are setting callback two times.

Here is optimized fragment class

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public SwipeRefreshLayout mswipeRefreshLayout;
    public static MyRecyclerAdapter searchAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "FirstFragment";
    MyRecyclerAdapter myRecyclerAdapter;
    ArrayList<DataStored> dataStoredArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ParseDataClass mparser;


    private void initView() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragment_view.findViewById(R.id.mFirstRecyclerview);
        mswipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) fragment_view.findViewById(R.id.swipelayoutm);
        mswipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshList();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        myRecyclerAdapter = new AdapterOrders(getActivity(), dataStoredArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);
        searchAdapter = myRecyclerAdapter;
    }

    private void setParser() {
        mparser = new ParseDataClass(getActivity());
        mparser.setOnDataRetrievalCallback(new OnDataRetrievalCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDataRetrieval(ArrayList<DataStored> dataSet) {
                mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (dataSet != null)
                    dataStoredArrayList = dataSet;
                myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private void refreshList() {
        mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        setParser();
        mparser.execute("http://192.168.3.10/fetchtext.php", "1");
    }

    View fragment_view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        fragment_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, null);
        initView();
        setAdapter();
        setParser();
        refreshList();
        return fragment_view;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I avoid calling two times adatper and callback could you edit code for me ?

Comment: I am calling callback to get refresh array and calling adapter again to set refresh array to adapter is there any other best way please guide me

Comment: Dude i said you to paste the your full code of fragment class, so that i edit it for you.

Comment: Why are you passing swipeRefreshLayout in adapter. I never need to do so, and why have you set setOnScrollChangeListener? Let me know so i can optimise.

Comment: I have passed swipeRefreshLayout to adapter by mistakenly

Comment: I set setOnScrollChangeListener because my RecyclerView  was not Scorlling properly sometimes I was scrolling RecyclerView but it call SwipeRefreshLayout and refresh data

Comment: I have edited your class for you. let me know if you face any issue. post your layout file too, so i can see if there's any scrolling issue in xml

Comment: Not working. giving error OnDataRetrievalCallback.onDataRetrieval(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference

Comment: I could not test it cause i did not have your adapter and parser, i fix it. Wait a bit.

Comment: this can not happen because i initiated mparser before using it.

Comment: See answer, I added one line if (mparser == null) setParser(); in method refreshList() for checking for escaping nullPointerException. But you should debug this issue should not persist.

Comment: first it gives me null/empty RecyclerView when I refresh ListView then it gives me this error

Comment: At first your list is not populated automatically, check if data is coming from server.

Comment: and see if dataStoredArrayList  is not cloned at adapter class, because it will not change recycler view if cloned.

Comment: there is no issue from server side the above code which I have uploaded in question is working fine but you said I am calling Adapter and Callback again that's why

Comment: Okay i got issue, may be your ParseDataClass makes callback null after use. just call setParser(); before execute a new api.

Comment: You need not to write same code two times in any java class, always write reusable code Majid.

Answer (score 0):

```
mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

call this in your listner :

```
    mparser.setOnDataRetrievalCallback(new OnDataRetrievalCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataRetrieval(ArrayList<DataStored> dataSet) {
                            mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); 
                            dataStoredArrayList.addAll(dataSet);
                            myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
```

and remove `mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` from `onRefresh()` method